# Fullcalendar cannot display the new event when switch month back

Tags: events, fullcalendar

I add a new event to fullcalendar, it displays well, but when I go to next month and switch back, it disappears! But the old event displays well, why? How can I display all events?

The detail like:

1. I have two events: event1, event2
   coming from a database and when
   FullCalendar initializes, I add them to
   the Calendar, displays well.
2. Then I add another event: event3 to calendar, can display well.
3. I go to next month.
4. I switch back, I find only event1 and event2 displayed, and event3
   disappeared?

Does anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

sounds like you could use the renderEvent method with the 'stick' parameters:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {...}, true);

Comment: How would one accomplish this in Drupal?